# Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider$Builder'

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-2

I'm following the google instructions on building a map in android and so far I've been sucessful.

However, when I've tried to add a heatmap with a few lat lng's the app fails and I get the following error message

```
Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider$Builder', referenced from method com.example.heatmap.MainActivity.addHeatMap
```

I've searched everywhere and I can't find a solution to this. The Utils lib is added correctly as is the google play services, as per the online instructions. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

For Clarity, the map works fine, but when I call the heatmap method the app fails.

```
package com.example.heatmap;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;

/**
 * This shows how to create a simple activity with a map and a marker on the map.
 * <p>
 * Notice how we deal with the possibility that the Google Play services APK is not
 * installed/enabled/updated on a user's device.
 */
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    static final LatLng Ireland = new LatLng(53.5056, -7.8289);
    static final LatLng IrelandCenter = new LatLng(53.4026137,-7.969749234);
    private UiSettings Settings;
    private JSONObject testjson = new JSONObject();
    private static String file = "sample_locations.json";

    private HeatmapTileProvider mProvider;
    private TileOverlay mOverlay;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // First incarnation of this activity.
            mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        } else {
            // Reincarnated activity. The obtained map is the same map instance in the previous
            // activity life cycle. There is no need to reinitialize it.
            mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        }

        setUpMapIfNeeded();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
                locateMapIreland();
                createMarker();
                addHeatMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */






    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        Settings = mMap.getUiSettings();

        Settings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        Settings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        Settings.setCompassEnabled(true);
    }

    private void locateMapIreland(){
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(IrelandCenter,7));
    }

    private void createMarker(){
        Marker testMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(Ireland)
                                  .draggable(true)
                                  .title("Title text")
                                  .snippet("Snippet text")
                                  .flat(false));

        testMarker.showInfoWindow();

    }

    private void addHeatMap() {
        List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        LatLng one = new LatLng(53.998,-8.624);
        list.add(one);
        LatLng two = new LatLng(52.443,-8.988);
        list.add(two);
        LatLng three = new LatLng(52.286,-8.319);
        list.add(three);
        LatLng four = new LatLng(54.162,-8.253);
        list.add(four);
        LatLng five = new LatLng(53.364,-6.453);
        list.add(five);

        List <LatLng> listTwo = null;

        // Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.


        // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
        mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(list)
            .build();
        // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
        mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, you need to make sure you've added both google play services and google util libraries as libs to your project, under the properties tab. The tutorials don't show this and only show how to add play services as a lib to utils

Answer (score 0):

The online instructions didn't work for me, I used this steps:

1. In the Main Application > Select project properties > Go to Java Build Path > Add Jars > Select the bin folder of Library > choose library.jar
2. In the Library project > Select project properties > Android > Check isLibrary
3. In the MainApplication > Select project properties > Go to Android > Add reference to Library in the Library section.

I found this steps in stackoverflow, but I don't find the link.

Answer (score 0):

import the library, go to project properties, go to android, then check the " is library" add app_compact then, go to library properties, go to android tools and add support library ! then add the library ( both play services library and map util library )to your demo_project, this worked for me :)